# Cd Drive keeps opening on its own. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed the Ubuntu alongside with Windows 10, but the problem is 'Cd drive keeps opening after every once a while.' I tried disabling the boot from CD Drive in boot settings. Didn't worked!!  Can anyone help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
eject -v -a off
```

**explanation:**

This  option controls the auto-eject mode, supported by some devices.  When enabled, the drive automatically ejects when the device is
            closed.